# How to write a letter of complaint about mean girls

Tags: work-environment, united-kingdom, bullying, behavior

I am in the UK. I understand that there are 'protected characteristics' that one is fully justified in raising complaints about if violated and are taken very seriously by the management however, people often dismiss mean girl, relational bullying in the workplace. For example, personal comments on appearance, weight,  and eating habits, excluding behaviour, rumour spreading, relational aggression, etc.

It is difficult to prove by its very nature, yet the impact it has on my metal health and wellbeing is clear for all to see.

Are there any key legal phrases  that I could use  in my formal letter of complaint that would be taken seriously eg my dignity has been violated, hostile environment, disrespectful etc.

Comment: Are you able to give some examples of the behaviour you are talking about?

Comment: This is more of a legal question. In Canada, one might claim workplace harassment (doesn't have to be sexual or racial). Not all countries take it all that seriously though.

Comment: @gregorycurrie eg Personal comments on appearance, weight, eating habits. Excluding behaviour, rumour spreading, relational aggression etc.

Answer (score 6):

You take a read of the following: https://www.gov.uk/workplace-bullying-and-harassment, and also https://www.nhs.uk/mental-health/advice-for-life-situations-and-events/support-for-workplace-bullying/.

Also you could take a look at the following: https://www.nationalbullyinghelpline.co.uk/employees.html

The keywords there are bullying and harassment.

From the examples you raised, it looks like it is more bullying than harassment.

But that doesn't mean you can't speak with HR.

You should clearly outline the behaviours that are having an impact on your mental health. Your employer has a Duty of Care to you, and that includes your mental wellbeing.